# array inside structs c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm porting my program to C++, but I'm having a little bit of trouble.
I have this code in C# creating a byte[] :

```
writer.New(0x484700C0);
    {
        writer += Functions.PadString("PTEmu", 0x10);
        writer += new byte[] { 0xC9, 0x32, 0xE0, 0x4D, 0xEB, 0x01 };
        writer.SkipBytes(6);
        writer += 1;
        writer += channels.Count; // sub count


        for (int i = 0; i < channels.Count; i++)
        {
            writer += Functions.PadString(channels[i].Item4, 0x20); // len = 0x20
            writer += Functions.PadString(channels[i].Item2, 0x14);
            writer += Functions.PadString(channels[i].Item2, 0x14);
            writer += Functions.PadString(channels[i].Item2, 0x14);


            writer += channels[i].Item3; // int, size = 4
            writer += channels[i].Item3;
            writer += channels[i].Item3;
            writer += 0;
        }


        writer += Functions.PadString("Clan", 32);
        writer += Functions.PadString("127.0.0.1", 0x14);
        writer += Functions.PadString("127.0.0.1", 0x14);
        writer += Functions.PadString("127.0.0.1", 0x14);
        writer += 80;
        writer += 80;
        writer += 80;
        writer.SkipBytes(12);
    }
```

I thought about doing something like:

```
struct PT_ServerList{
    int size;
    int opcode;
    char server[0x10];
    char bla[6];
    int reserved1;
    short reserved2;
    int unknow;
    int serverCount;
    ServerInfo servers[];
};
```

But after the servers[] I'd need to add more variables, but then the compiler doesnt accept the struct. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/):

```
struct PT_ServerList {
    ...
    std::vector<ServerInfo> servers;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use either:

```
ServerInfo *servers;
```

(in which case you'd need to allocate the array using "new[]" and deallocate it using "delete[]"); or:

```
std::vector<ServerInfo> servers;
```

(In which case you should consult the [std::vector documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) for information about how to use it, if you haven't used `std::vector` before.

Comment: it still not working, I wrote the contents to a .dat file and it is not showing the contents of servers

Comment: I saw in olly, that the contents of servers is being added in another location of memory, not inside the PT_ServerList structure